# Avoiding Service Locator with AutoFac 2

Tags: ioc-container, autofac

I'm building an application which uses AutoFac 2 for DI.  I've been [reading](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/BestPractices) that using a static IoCHelper (Service Locator) should be avoided.

**IoCHelper.cs**

```
public static class IoCHelper
{
    private static AutofacDependencyResolver _resolver;

    public static void InitializeWith(AutofacDependencyResolver resolver)
    {
        _resolver = resolver;
    }

    public static T Resolve<T>()
    {
        return _resolver.Resolve<T>();
    }
}
```

From answers to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726606/issue-with-autofac-2-and-mvc2-using-httprequestscoped/2735667#2735667), I found a way to help reduce the need for using my IoCHelper in my UnitOfWork through the use of [Auto-generated Factories](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/NewInV2).  Continuing down this path, I'm curious if I can completely eliminate my IoCHelper.

Here is the scenario:

I have a static Settings class that serves as a wrapper around my configuration implementation.  Since the Settings class is a dependency to a majority of my other classes, the wrapper keeps me from having to inject the settings class all over my application.

**Settings.cs**

```
public static class Settings
{
    public static IAppSettings AppSettings
    {
        get
        {
            return IoCHelper.Resolve<IAppSettings>();
        }
    }
}

public interface IAppSettings
{
    string Setting1 { get; }
    string Setting2 { get; }
}

public class AppSettings : IAppSettings
{
    public string Setting1
    {
        get
        {
            return GetSettings().AppSettings["setting1"];
        }
    }

    public string Setting2
    {
        get
        {
            return GetSettings().AppSettings["setting2"];
        }
    }

    protected static IConfigurationSettings GetSettings()
    {
        return IoCHelper.Resolve<IConfigurationSettings>();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to handle this without using a service locator and without having to resort to injecting AppSettings into each and every class?  Listed below are the 3 areas in which I keep leaning on ServiceLocator instead of constructor injection:

- AppSettings
- Logging
- Caching

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would rather inject `IAppSettings` into every class that needs it just to keep them clean from the hidden dependency on `Settings`. Question is, do you really need to sprinkle that dependency into each and every class?

If you really want to go with a static `Settings` class I would at least try to make it test-friendly/fakeable. Consider this:

```
public static class Settings
{
    public static Func<IAppSettings> AppSettings { get; set; }
}
```

And where you build your container:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
...
var container = builder.Build();

Settings.AppSettings = () => container.Resolve<IAppSettings>();
```

This would allow to swap out with fakes during test:

```
Settings.AppSettings = () => new Mock<IAppSettings>().Object;
```

Now the `AppSettings` class (which I assume there is only one of) you could do with regular constructor injection. I assume also that you really want to do a resolve on each call to your settings properties, thus injecting a factory delegate that retrieves an instance when needed. If this is not needed you should of course inject the `IConfigurationSettings` service directly.

```
public class AppSettings : IAppSettings
{
    private readonly Func<IConfigurationSettings> _configurationSettings;

    public AppSettings(Func<IConfigurationSettings> configurationSettings)
    {
        _configurationSettings = configurationSettings;
    }

    public string Setting1
    {
        get
        {
            return _configurationSettings().AppSettings["setting1"];
        }
    }

    public string Setting2
    {
        get
        {
            return _configurationSettings().AppSettings["setting2"];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a good point.  Truthfully, I probably don't need to inject those dependencies into EVERY class, but for cases when I have the same dependency being injected into a large number of classes, I was just curious if there is some DI best practice for this.

Comment: See my updated answer. Truth be told, I've been forced to do this on one occasion: when constructor injection could not be used (designer required a parameterless constructor).